# (wx)Maxima: enumerate lists so they start at 0?

Tags: list, maxima, wxmaxima

Is it possible to change Maxima's default enumeration of list items so it starts at 0 as opposed to 1?

Comment: No, there's no way to change list indexing to start at anything other than 1. (There are various kinds of arrays and some of them start at 0, however, arrays are pretty far from interchangeable with lists, so there would be a lot of effort involved, with only the slight benefit of changing the base index from 1 to 0.)